# Issue when trying to run two migrations with same name in different folders Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two folders in my migrations:

- `database/migrations/simulator`
- `database/migrations/tasks`

Inside each one i have a migration for users like: `create_users_table`.

And each migration inside a folder have different connections to different databases like this e.g.:

```php
Schema::connection('mysql_simulator')
    ->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**The issue is:** Laravel don't allow me to run these migrations properly.

When i try to run this command: `php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/simulator"`

The `users` table migrate normally,  but if after that i try to run the same with `tasks` folder: `php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/tasks"`

I got this error: `Nothing to migrate.`

But if i try to reset my migrations from **`tasks`** folder: `php artisan migrate:reset --path="database/migrations/tasks`

It shows me that:

```
Migration not found: 2021_02_13_194359_create_textures_table
Migration not found: 2021_02_04_224957_create_image_simulation_table
Migration not found: 2021_02_03_192318_create_images_table
Migration not found: 2021_01_29_170555_create_simulations_table
Migration not found: 2021_01_29_170326_create_addresses_table
Migration not found: 2021_01_29_170138_create_phones_table
Migration not found: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migration not found: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migration not found: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migration not found: 2021_03_10_213837_create_users_table
```

Basically it shows me all the tables from the other folder (not the one i run the command) i ran my `tasks` migration but it showed me that all my `simulator` migrations was not found.

So i don't know that is happening, seems like Laravel is reading all migrations from different folders as one, i just need to create the same migration name in different folders and run it without conflicts, is it possible in Laravel?.

Comment: Do you have Users (and all other) migrations with the same name?? I mean do you have for example "2021_03_10_213837_create_users_table" migration in "tasks" folder, and the migration with the same in "simulator" folder

Comment: Yes, It have the same name but different folders, i just noticed now that laravel doesnt allow me to have same class name of migrations, no matters if it is in different folders, i think i'll have to put a prefix in each migration to get this working.

Comment: No matter where you can put them. Laravel allows to run migrations with unique names. After running some migrations you can check that in DB (in "migrations" table) there are stored all the runned migrations. So you need to rename the migrations from 1-st or 2-nd folder. For example you can rename all migrations only from "tasks" folder like this: "2021_03_10_213837_create_users_table" -> "2021_03_10_000000_create_users_table". (as you can see, there are changed part 000000)

Answer (score 0):

probably these are migrations that you have removed them from your project migrations directory after a successful migrate,
when you run `php artisan migrate`
Laravel logs the successful ones in migrations table in your DB , so when you delete them , this error comes up , try to delete them from migrations table also